# Where is this specific setting I forgot the name? Using Sony Xperia Z3, Android 4.4.4

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, settings, sony-xperia-z

While getting used to my new phone, an assistant showed up, asking me to configure some time settings regarding night & charging, time settings when I plug in/out my charger cable, and alarms, etc.

Now, I wanted to review those changes I made, but I cannot find those settings anymore!
Anyone knows whats the setting name or menu item for that specific assistant on that phone (Sony Xperia Z3)?

Comment: On Nexus, if I go to Settings - Apps - All, I can find "Google One Time Init", which I believe is the first-time wizard. However, there is no launcher or any way to access that. I'd assume if I clear its data, it would run again on next boot, but I didn't try it. Perhaps there's a similar app on Sony.

Comment: Related, but might be device-specific: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/67177/how-can-i-get-the-first-boot-android-welcome-screen-again-without-doing-a-factor

Comment: Thx @andrew, but that wasn't it. After searching through the phone some more, I found it: for future readers, its called "Smart Connect". The reason its not to be found in any preference setting, is that it has its own icon and comes pre-installed. For my specific case, I then select "Night", where I can see all the additional tasks the phone does "automagically" (and that cause troubles ;)

Comment: Good to know you found the solution! Consider to post it as answer instead of comment. Self-answer is encouraged too :)

Answer (score 1):

[Answer based on my previous comment] 
The feature/setting is called "Smart Connect". The reason it's not to be found in any preference setting, is that it has its own icon and comes pre-installed (I guess on most Sony devices). For my specific case, I then select "Night", where I can see all the additional tasks the phone does "automagically" (and that cause troubles ;)
Other events for automation include "Music on the go", and "Music at home".