# Redo one-time setup?

Tags: cyanogenmod, encryption, 5.1-lollipop

Due to a flaw in the way that Android does decryption*, I setup my devices by skipping through all the first boot setup stuff provided by CyanogenMod and Android.

I then immediately go into the settings and encrypt the device. This makes it so that there's no accounts ever stored on the device in plain-text.

Is there a way, after I encrypt the device, to go through the one-time initialization again? Are there applications for which I can simply wipe the data which will trigger the next boot to run through first time setup again?

Comment: Very related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/67177/how-can-i-get-the-first-boot-android-welcome-screen-again-without-doing-a-factor (there's an interesting answer, but we couldn't get it work)